# R notebook generates a blank plot in addition to actual plot

Tags: r, plot, knitr, r-markdown, rnotebook

I am using R notebook. This is my chunk:

````
```{r}
test = matrix(rnorm(200), 20, 10)
pheatmap::pheatmap(test)
```
````

I guess it's due to the way `pheatmap` generates the plot, but it actually generates a blank plot first. Thus, this is the output I see:
[image]

How do I get rid of that first image? I see it in the RStudio output (screenshot above) and in the `.nb.html` file. If I knit to HTML, the blank plot is not there.

I tried different `fig.keep` options. They work when I knit to HTML, but they don't seem to have an effect in the `.nb.html` file. How can I get rid of it?

Update: This issue was [fixed in pheatmap](https://github.com/raivokolde/pheatmap/issues/37). It may still be applicable to other scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

This is weird. Try this:

````
```{r}
library(pheatmap)
p <- pheatmap(test, silent = TRUE)
plot(p$gtable)
```
````

It produces exactly what you describe. Now, split it into two chunks.

````
```{r}
library(pheatmap)
p <- pheatmap(test, silent = TRUE)
```

```{r}
plot(p$gtable)
```
````

It works! I have no idea why, though.

Comment: That works for me too. It's actually a slightly different output, though. For example, I get a gray background with `plot(p$gtable)`.

Comment: @burger You can get white background by executing `grid.draw(p$gtable)` instead of `plot(p$gtable)`.